# Strange pjax behavior: GET request initiates after a pjax request

Tags: pjax

The problem is, as soon as pjaxed request finishes, pjax also initiates a normal GET request.

My codes are like this:

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function(event){
    alert("end");
    inpjax = false;
});

$(document).on('pjax:timeout', function(event) {
    alert("timeout")
    event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('pjax:error', function() {
    alert("error");
});

$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
    alert("success");
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    inpjax = false;
    $('.pj').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!inpjax)
        {
            inpjax = true;
            $.pjax({
                timeout:    5000,
                url:        $(this).attr('href'),
                container:  '#codeport'
            });     
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, it should give me an alert on different stiuations, but I only get alert on pjax:end event, and after that alert, pjax initiates normal GET request, timing is like this:

```
[17:36:02.002] GET http://localhost/abstract?_pjax=%23codeport [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 86 ms]
[17:36:02.170] GET http://localhost/abstract [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 73 ms]
```

I don't get timeout, error or success alert.

What could be causing this? Please help...

**SOLUTION:**

The problem turned out to be that my serverside code was responding with a full page, and that was causing a second GET request. So if this problem happens to you too, make sure that your server side code responds correctly to PJAX requests.

Comment: does your server support pjax ? did u read this manual? https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax ?

Comment: Maybe it is important to use yui for this ? http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/pjax/

Comment: @Arekkusandaa.Irujasukin this is the response to the message you deleted:
Why would it matter how you use it?
Anyways, I changed the code like this:
`if ($.support.pjax) {
  $(document).on('click', '.pj', function(event) {
 var container = "#codeport";
 $.pjax.click(event, {container: container})
  })
}
else alert("No pjax support.");`
But same thing is happening, nothing changed.
`[18:11:15.937] GET http://localhost/abstract?_pjax=%23codeport [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 96 ms]
[18:11:16.069] GET http://localhost/abstract [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 91 ms]`
Also, my browser supports ajax, of course.

Comment: okay, i understand. i meant what if your server side is not prepared ? check this `server side` paragraph https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#server-side

Comment: @Arekkusandaa.Irujasukin

Of course server side is prepared, but why would it matter??? Even if it is not prepared, pjax should load full page into #codeport element, not make another GET request. This can't be the cause behind my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- styles, scripts, etc -->
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
    Download content from <a href="/page/2"> the other site </a>?.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try to add pjax to an element which you want to get event messages from like `$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container')`

Comment: So in my case I did this: `$(document).pjax('.pj', '#codeport');`

But works no differently then previous codes.

Comment: Finally I found the solution, it seems that you were right about serverside, because of I were using wrong logical operator, pjax request was loading a full page. I thought it can't be a problem, but opposite to my guess, it was causing a second request. So I fixed it now and it works perfect. I can't believe I did such a stupid mistake :D Thanks for your time, I select this answer because of your time.

Comment: @MahmutAkkuş corresponging the probability of a situation when someone has faced to this problem, could be more helpful if you could edit your topic body at the bottom appending an 'update' with explaination of your mistake. As for me, usually , i spending long time searching where i could be wrong in my code, surfing the internet too, so it's pretty common scenario i guess, i mean with these 'stupid mistakes' ))

Comment: Yeah me too, before creating my stackoverflow account and asking this question, I learned so many things and discovered my stupid mistakes from contributions in here, so I'll let this be my contribution :D
Also I was using Chrome first, and was not able to look at the response of pjax request, so couldn't see it was responsing a full page. I saw it when I used Firefox for it.